# UIPageViewController (horizontal) inside another UIPageViewController (vertical) (2 axis)

Tags: ios, xcode, uipageviewcontroller

I would like 2 UIPageViewController to work together fine with 2 axis (vertical and horizontal) :

The problem is my vertical subview (pvcV) take over the horizontal subview (pvcH) because I declare it after the horizontal one. How can I do to make both work together? I've search a lot for this kind of code here but didnt find out...

Here's my code in the **RootViewController**:

```
self.pvcH = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:nil];
self.pvcH.delegate = self;

self.pvcV = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationVertical options:nil];
self.pvcV.delegate = self;

TCDataViewController *startingViewController = [self.modelController viewControllerAtIndex:0 storyboard:self.storyboard];
NSArray *viewControllers = @[startingViewController];
self.pvcH.dataSource = self.modelController;
self.pvcV.dataSource = self.modelController;

[self.pvcV setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:NULL];
[self.pvcH setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:NULL];

[self addChildViewController:self.pvcH];
[self addChildViewController:self.pvcV];
[self.view addSubview:self.pvcH.view];
[self.view addSubview:self.pvcV.view];
```

Many thanks if you can help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put one inside of each other.

For example: You'll end up having a horizontal pageViewController in which every page of it is a vertical pageViewController in which every page is your final content (TCDateViewController in your case, iI think)

Comment: That was what I had in mind.
Took me a long time but it seems ok now! I can both scroll horizontally and vertically :)

Thx!